# java timezones and summer- wintertime

Tags: java, timezone

We have a java programm which uses the -Duser.timezone parameter at startup:

-Duser.timezone="CET"

This is neccessary because we can't rely on the servers internal clock (admins playing around, setting wrong timezones and so on, don't ask :-( ) and it is important that the timezone of the frontend matches the backend.

As this program is not restarted regularly (it is a server) I was wondering what happens when we switch from winter- to summertime? Does it switch automatically or do we have to restart the server?

Thanks and regards,
Alex

Edit: It might be possible that java determines the correct timezone with ervery call to a function which uses dates. But it might also be possible that java determines the correct timezone once at startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time in Java is just a simple long value (milliseconds since 1970) without any information about the time zone. The `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` also store the date/time internally as milliseconds since 1970, but with UTC time zone.

The time zone comes into play, when you format a date/time for output or when you parse a date/time from a string. The time zone information you set via `-Duser.timezone` will be used at that time.

So it should work and a little test also shows it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(2013, 2, 30, 23, 0, 0);
    long start = c.getTimeInMillis();
    long oneHour = 1000 * 60 * 60;
    long t = start;
    for (long i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(new Date(t));            
        t = t + oneHour;
    }
}
```

using `-Duser.timezone=GMT` it will print: (no switch)

```
Sat Mar 30 23:00:00 GMT 2013
Sun Mar 31 00:00:00 GMT 2013
Sun Mar 31 01:00:00 GMT 2013
Sun Mar 31 02:00:00 GMT 2013
Sun Mar 31 03:00:00 GMT 2013
```

using `-Duser.timezone=CET` it will print: (switch at 2am)

```
Sat Mar 30 23:00:00 CET 2013
Sun Mar 31 00:00:00 CET 2013
Sun Mar 31 01:00:00 CET 2013
Sun Mar 31 03:00:00 CEST 2013
Sun Mar 31 04:00:00 CEST 2013
```

using `-Duser.timezone=EET` it will print: (Eastern European Time, one hour after CET)

```
Sat Mar 30 23:00:00 EET 2013
Sun Mar 31 00:00:00 EET 2013
Sun Mar 31 01:00:00 EET 2013
Sun Mar 31 02:00:00 EET 2013
Sun Mar 31 04:00:00 EEST 2013
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer and the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure setting `user.timezone` sets the default time zone just like `TimeZone.setDefault()`. So, it won't get updated for daylight savings time or other changes.

If you really have to do this, my suggestion would be to create a custom request to your server that can change the time zone by calling `TimeZone.setDefault()`. This way you can change it when required without a server restart. Obviously, this request needs to be secured so that only admins can execute it.

Answer (score 0):

## `CET` is a psuedo-zone

Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

## `Continent/Region`

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`.

Perhaps by `CET` you actually mean a time zone such as `Europe/Luxembourg` or `Europe/Gibraltar`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Gibralter" ) ;
```

The `TimeZone` class is now legacy, part of the terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Use only the modern *java.time* classes instead.

## Proper name adjusts for DST

> As this program is not restarted regularly (it is a server) I was wondering what happens when we switch from winter- to summertime?

If you use the proper name as shown above, and you keep the *tzdata* data file up-to-date in your JVM installation, then the Daylight Saving Time (DST) cutovers are handled automatically for you when using [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now() ;  // Omitting the optional `ZoneId` argument means the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied, looking up the current offset in use at this moment for the JVM's current default time zone.
```

Let's look at what happens during the DST cutover in Spring of 2020, at 2 AM on the 29th of March. We get the time at one minute before 2 AM. Then we add a minute. Notice how the **time-of-day jumps from 1:59 AM to 3 AM** rather than 2 AM because of the DST "spring-ahead" adjustment in wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Gibraltar" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2020 , 3 , 29 , 1 , 59 , 0 , 0 , z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtMinuteLater = zdt.plusMinutes( 1 ) ;  // Notice how the time-of-day jumps to 3 AM rather than 2 AM.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "zdt.toString(): " + zdt ) ;
System.out.println( "zdtMinuteLater.toString(): " + zdtMinuteLater ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/pPms6H).

> zdt.toString(): 2020-03-29T01:59+01:00[Europe/Gibraltar]
>
> zdtMinuteLater.toString(): 2020-03-29T03:00+02:00[Europe/Gibraltar]

## Do not rely on default

You can write your code to not rely on the JVM's current default time zone.

The line of code shown earlier (`ZonedDateTime.now()`) is *not* what I recommend. That line omits the optional `ZoneId` argument. Instead, I recommend always passing your desired/expected time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Gibralter" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtGibralter = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId ) ;
```